# Inline todo-notes including verbatim blocks?

Tags: verbatim, todonotes

I'm making a major change to a document, and I want to turn some quite large sections into notes using `todonotes`.  According to the documentation, this can be done with

```
\todo[inline,caption={My Caption}]{
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}

< all my stuff >

\end{minipage}
}
```

The trouble is that my sections include clumps of computer code, either with the `verbatim` environment, or with the `lstlistings` environment from the `listings` package.  And each one throws an error about the brackets - the closing bracket of the `todo` material seems to be mishandled by the other environments, even though they're in a minipage.  I can get the correct visual effect by putting all computer code into `\texttt{   }` but then I need to fiddle with newlines and horizontal whitespace to show indentation.

Here's a minimal non-working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{todonotes}

\begin{document}
This is a test of an inline note:

\todo[inline,caption={My caption}]{
  \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    A test of verbatim:
\begin{verbatim}
And this...
    ... is this!
\end{verbatim}
  \end{minipage}
}

\end{document}
```

The error is: `Argument of \@xverbatim has an extra }.`  I've tried using `Verbatim` from the `fancyvrb` package, and also the `listings` package, with the same error.

So - how can I include a verbatim environment inside a minipage inside a todo note?

Comment: There's another method using cprotect, see my answer here [How to use markdown in todonotes? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/625548/how-to-use-markdown-in-todonotes/625597#625597)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the verbatim in a box prior to the inline `\todo` and then recall it.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{todonotes,verbatimbox}

\begin{document}
This is a test of an inline note:

\begin{myverbbox}{\verbA}
And this#^\...
    ... is this!
\end{myverbbox}

\todo[inline,caption={My caption}]{
  \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    A test of verbatim:\strut\\
\verbA
  \end{minipage}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]