# How to use markdown in todonotes?

Tags: markdown, todonotes

I use todonotes, especially in the coordination of bigger projects.
Especially in the drafting and quick brainstorming phase I'd love to be able to just use markdown inside todonotes to not waste time with nesting itemize etc.

Sadly, i can't seem to make it work:
my many attempts to put a markdown env inside a todonote like this

`\todo[...]{\begin{markdown}...\end{markdown}}`

have failed with many errors (mostly seems to be runaway arg) sounding something like this:

`Argument of ^^M has an extra }.`

Any ideas / help / pointers?

##### MCVE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{markdown}
\usepackage{todonotes}

\begin{document}

% normal markdown works:
\begin{markdown}
* woah
* bullets
\end{markdown}

% todonotes work
\todo[inline,prepend,caption={WOAH}]{yay}

% todonotes with itemize work
\todo[inline,prepend,caption={WOAH}]{yay
\begin{itemize}
    \item woah
    \item complicated bullets
\end{itemize}
}

% todonotes with markdown break
\todo[inline,prepend,caption={WOAH}]{nay
\begin{markdown}
* woah
* bullets easy
* boom
\end{markdown}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Are your todonotes also inline in your real document, or is that just for this example? And do you want to use other parts or markdown as well, or is it only for easy bullet lists?

Comment: Most likely [todonotes - Inline todo-notes including verbatim blocks? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/487681/inline-todo-notes-including-verbatim-blocks)

Comment: @user202729 while the question you linked would most probably work it does sort of fail the goal of the OP to make it easier to include lists, because now they would need extra commands/environments to store a box and use it later.

Comment: Also, it seems that you're using LuaLaTeX, in that case no need for inputenc and fontenc. (... see the warning...)

Comment: @Marijn yes, they're inline. We like to draft/outline in the todonotes, then use `disable` to hide the block keeping the outline in the source. Not super fancy markdown, but nested lists, links, code etc. would be nice.

Comment: @user202729 thx for the pointers, but @Marijn is right... i'd actually like to simplify it. If possible even to a degree where i could define a simple `\todoPersonA{...}` for each person involved where `...` can just also include or completely be markdown.

Comment: That would be a different question. It should not be too hard with cprotect; alternatively catcode manipulation can be used, see [verbatim - How can one construct a macro that contains a pythontex or fancyvrb environment? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/543921/how-can-one-construct-a-macro-that-contains-a-pythontex-or-fancyvrb-environment?noredirect=1&lq=1) for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, `markdown` is a verbatim environment so it cannot be used inside the argument of most commands.

See https://texfaq.org/FAQ-verbwithin for more details.

A fix that does not involve much code change uses `cprotect`. Note the extra brace group around `\todo[inline,prepend,caption={WOAH}]`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{markdown}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{cprotect}

\begin{document}

\cprotect{\todo[inline,prepend,caption={WOAH}]}{nay
\begin{markdown}
* woah
* bullets easy
* boom
\end{markdown}
}

\end{document}
```

For explanation, see the documentation of `cprotect` package.

Note that `\cprotect[om]\todo[inline, ...]{nay ...}` does not work because the optional argument must *not* be protected (the details what protect means is quite complex, see [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/622512/how-does-cprotect-work/622513#622513) for more details.)

---

Alternatively it's possible to redefine `\todo` like this

```
\NewCommandCopy\oldtodo\todo
\outer\def\todo[#1]{\icprotect{\oldtodo[#1]}}
```

- See `cprotect` documentation for why `icprotect` should be used.
- `\NewCommandCopy` is required because internally `\todo` uses some mechanism to protect it (prevent it from being expanded in expand-only context).

Comment: (remark: in the last method the argument wrapped in `[...]` is *not* optional. Just for demonstration purposes.)

Comment: i'm pretty happy with the alternative re-defining todo here and going to accept this as an answer...

i however seem to be unable to define a `\newcommand{\todoPersonA}[2][]{\icprotect{\oldtodo[inline, prepend, caption={A}, #1]}{#2}}` on top of this (despite trying basically all bracketing combinations and `\def` based ones i could think of). Any obvious ideas on how to make something like `\todoPersonA{...\begin{markdown}yay, markdown here\end{markdown}...}` work too?

Comment: @JörnHees `\newcommand{\todoPersonA}[1][]{\icprotect{\todo[inline, prepend, caption={A}, #1]}}`.  (by the way, I recommend learning TeX properly instead of "programming by permutation".)

Comment: kudos!!! and WAT?!? (and: fair point if i didn't try understanding first combining what the `cprotect` package docs offer with what you showed... seeing your solution i clearly don't seem to understand why i need to pretend that `\todoPersonA` only has one arg here, but then can use it like i want with an optional and a mandatory one afterwards (`\todoPersonA[..., disable]{...\begin{markdown}...\end{markdown}...})`. So yeah, maybe some (La)TeX basics missing there, but i seem to fail at even phrasing a single google query that returns anything helpful :-/)

Comment: @JörnHees Well yes, I know how hard it is to come across good resources. Searching "LaTeX tutorial" etc. just result in typesetting tutorials, because way too few people cares about the programming details – anyway there's [tex core - What is the best way to learn TeX? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53/what-is-the-best-way-to-learn-tex?noredirect=1&lq=1)  and [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/621577/250119) for the resource list.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative approach to avoid markdown. Not that markdown is anything to be avoided, and I would recommend the [answer by user202729](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/625597/), but just to showcase some packages.

The following shows inline todonotes as a `tcolorbox`. Inside the tcolorbox is an `easylist`, which provides a simple syntax for (nested) lists similar to markdown. Also in the example is a raw link, a labeled link and some code.

The tcolorbox environments can be 'disabled' by redefining them as the comment environment from the `verbatim` package.

By copying the definition of the `itemize` style for `easylist` into the preamble as default the syntax for a list inside the document is simplified a bit (otherwise it would be `\begin{easylist}[itemize]`). Also the syntax for the other elements (links and code) should be relatively simple and fast to type.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[at]{easylist}
% set itemize style as default
\ListProperties(Hang=true,Space=4pt,Space*=4pt,Hide=1000,%
Margin1=1.5em,Style1*=\textbullet\hskip .5em,%
Margin2=3.7em,Style2*=--\hskip .5em,%
Margin3=5.9em,Style3*=$\ast$\hskip .5em,%
Margin4=7.8em,Style4*=$\cdot$\hskip .5em)%
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{verbatim} % for switching off tcolorbox
\tcbset{
  colback=red!5!white,
  colframe=red!75!black,
}

% uncomment the next line to disable tcolorbox
%\renewenvironment{tcolorbox}{\comment}{\endcomment}
\begin{document}
Some text

\begin{tcolorbox}[title=WOAH]
\begin{easylist}
@ item 1
@ item2
@@ nested item
@ item3
\end{easylist}
\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com}\\
\href{https://tex.stackexchange.com}{TeX.SE}\\
\verb+return "@#$%^&"+
\end{tcolorbox}

More text
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]